# Loading Raster and vector data In MapGuide using Maestro

Tags: raster, open-source-gis, vector, mapguide

I am new to Mapguide , working on it for my summer Internship.I have Installed it perfectly.
Now the task is to load vector data and Raster data in map Guide (mainly have to load *.shp files and *.tif files). I have find not much resource that provide exact steps. Also I don't know where to put data files ? In Repository or somewhere else ? How to link these file ?
Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use tiff and shp. How you use them in mapguide is via connectors/provider or data source.

This step should be quite well documented. Please refer to the manual for either maestro or mapguide.

By the way, here's a good start:

http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/maestro/UserGuides/FileFeatureSource

Good luck!